# GAE Endpoint Library for C# in Xamarin

Tags: google-app-engine, xamarin, google-cloud-endpoints

I currently using Android Studio to built my GAE endpoints and app.  However, I want to move to Xamarin, so I can build an iOS version of my app.

My plan is to continue to use Android Studio to build the endpoint client library and "migrate" it to Xamarin.

However, my challenge is finding any useful information to make this work.  Can someone advise?  Much appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Install pip if you don't have one sudo easy_install pip

Step 2: Install google client library generator pip install google-apis-client-generator

Step 3 : Hit the url in the browser by replacing the application ID https://{applicationId}.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis

Step 4 : Copy the the property in the json "discoveryRestUrl" It would look like https://{applicationId}.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/{your api name}/v1/rest

Step 5: Download the file from url and save it as rest.json

Step 6: use the below line generate_library --input=rest.json --language=csharp --output_dir={your output location}

Please refer this link might be useful for you.

https://sookocheff.com/post/appengine/cloud-endpoints/generating-a-c-sharp-client/

Also Refere: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloworld-dotnet