# Google App Engine with Xamarin

Tags: java, google-app-engine, xamarin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I have to develop my application for both Android and iOS. Thus I came to the conclusion to use Xamarin for developing the app. But furthermore I want to develop my backend with Google app engine `cloud endpoints`, because it is very convenient to use them.

Can I use Xamarin with the endpoints?

Comment: yes you can http://stackoverflow.com/a/39799416/142904

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the current answer is no.

Cloud endpoints only runs with Linux, and Xamarin does not build Linux applications.